# how to use nullif function in else part of case statement

Tags: sql, oracle, db2

I have case statement with nullif function...

```
case when itm>0 then itm else nullif(vnd||':','0:')||sty end
```

Whenever else part is executing if vnd is null nothing but 0 I am not getting sty column.
If vnd exist then I need to concate with ':' both vnd and sty values.

Comment: It is not clear what exactly you expect: when sty is null, when sty = 0, when sty != 0. Could you provide an example?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I entirely understand your question, but does this get you close to what you're looking for?

```
DECLARE @itm VARCHAR(10), @sty VARCHAR(10), @vnd VARCHAR(10)
SET @itm = '0'
SET @sty = '2'
SET @vnd = '3'

SELECT
case 
    when @itm>0 then @itm
    WHEN @itm <= 0 THEN ISNULL(@vnd, 0) + ':' + ISNULL(@sty, '0') 
    END
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not actually sure what you need here. I think I have an idea, but there needs to be some clarification. Are you saying that if vnd is null, then you're not getting the sty field?

If that's true, then DB2 is doing what you want, because concatenation of a null value to something else also returns a null.

```
CASE 
    WHEN itm > 0 THEN itm
    WHEN (vnd IS NULL OR vnd = 0) THEN sty
    ELSE vnd || ':' || sty
END
```

Comment: if vnd is null nothing but 0 and sty contains ABC then the output will be 0:ABC i dont want 0:ABC we required only ABC. if vnd and sty contains values (vnd:123 & sty:ABC)then the output should be 123:ABC